# json_encode() float precision in PHP7 and addition operation

Tags: php, json

I'm aware of the new `serialize_precision` setting in php.ini, It is set to `-1` and `precision` is `14` by default.

The result of the `php -r 'echo json_encode(2.49);'` command is `2.49`, as expected. But result of `php -r 'echo json_encode(2.09 + 0.4);'` is `2.4899999999999998`.

Why and how to fix it without changing php.ini configuration?

**EDIT:**
To explain more - this is not the issue with float math, this is about json_encode() issue, because plain addition `php -r 'echo 2.09 + 0.4;'` produces correct result of `2.49`.

My PHP version:

```
PHP 7.2.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2017 20:14:31) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c)     1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is expected behavior (but not obvious IMO), according to the discussion here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75800

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
This problem appears in the later version of 7.1(contains 7.1)

```
function _json_encode($arr) {
    $func = function($r)use(&$func){
        if ( is_array($r) ) {
            foreach($r as $k=>$v) {
                $r[$k] = $func($v);
            }
            return $r;
        } else if ( is_float($r) ) {
            return (float)(''.$r);
        } else {
            return $r;
        }
    };
    if ( version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.1', '>=') ) {
        $arr = $func($arr);
    }
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    return $arr;
}

echo _json_encode(2.09 + 0.4);// is 2.49
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: Could you please edit to explain more what your code does? It would greatly help the OP and anyone interested in understanding and implementing your solution.